# Create unlimited nested hierarchical array of child parent company Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, parent-child

I have a table `company_basics` which have `parent_id` and this child-parent relationship can go unlimited.

Currently, my code is

```
$company = \App\CompanyBasic::whereRaw('user_id = ' . Auth::user()->id . " AND parent_id = 0")->get();


//                echo "<pre>";
//                print_r($company);
//                echo "</pre>";

$companies = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($company as $single_company) {
    $companies[$count]['id'] = $single_company->id;
    $companies[$count]['comp_name'] = $single_company->comp_name;

    $child_company = \App\CompanyBasic::whereRaw('user_id = ' . Auth::user()->id . " AND parent_id = '" . $single_company->id . "'")->get();

    $child_count = 0;
    foreach($child_company as $single_child_company) {
        $companies[$count]['child'][$child_count]['id'] = $single_child_company->id;
        $companies[$count]['child'][$child_count]['comp_name'] = $single_child_company->comp_name;
        $child_count++;
    }

    echo "company id: " . $single_company->id . "<br>";
    $count++;
}
```

I get the parents only and loop through them to find child but this is one level down but I want to go unlimited levels down.

The returned code right now is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [comp_name] => Habib company
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [comp_name] => Child Company
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [comp_name] => Child Company
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [comp_name] => Adjacent Company
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [comp_name] => MSB34
        )

)
```

Comment: You could look into recursive functions. They handle unlimited depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rypskar suggested, you should use a recursion.

I suggest you to use [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php) that will use itself inside of it (that is called `closure`) and do something like this:

```
 $userId = Auth::user()->id;

 $getChildOf = function ($parent) use ($userId, &$getChildOf) {

        $company   = \App\CompanyBasic::whereRaw('user_id = ' . $userId . " AND parent_id = " . $parent)->get();
        $companies = false;

        if ($company->isNotEmpty()) {
            $companies = array();

            foreach ($company as $single_company) {
                $companies[] = array(
                    'id'        => $single_company->id,
                    'comp_name' => $single_company->comp_name,
                    'child'     => $getChildOf($single_company->id),
                );
                echo "company id: " . $single_company->id . "<br>";
            }
        }

        return $companies;
  };

 $companies = $getChildOf(0);
```

Here the anonymous function passed to variable `$getChildOf` which is used for itself.

I've removed your `$count` variable to simplify the code.

By the way, you should understand that this code will preform a database query on each iteration, so it will substantially increase server load

Also, injecting variables to SQL queries with concatenation is insecure and considered to be a bad practice. You should consider to use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)